# Can't import npm modules in commonjs with rollup : "require is not defined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, commonjs, rollup

I work on an ES6 project that I transpile using rollup and babel. It works well except when I try to import npm modules that use commonjs (and particularly require('something')) getting an error "require is not defined" in my browser (which means it hasn't properly compiled node modules from commonjs to ES5). However, I use *rollup-plugin-node-resolve* and *rollup-plugin-commonjs*, that should do that job if I've understood properly...

Here are my rollup config file:

```
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';
import eslint from 'rollup-plugin-eslint';
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve'; // to import node_modules packages easily
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs'; // convert commonjs to es6 (in case you use require)

export default {
  input: 'src/main.js',
  output: {
      file:'build/index.js',
      format: 'iife'
  },
  sourcemap: 'inline',
  plugins: [
    resolve({
      jsnext: true,
      main: true,
      browser: true
    }),
    commonjs({
        include: 'src/**'
    }),
    eslint({
      exclude: [
        'src/styles/**',
      ]
    }),
    babel({
      exclude: 'node_modules/**',
    })
  ],
};
```

and my babel config file:

```
{
    "presets": [
        [
           "es2015",
           {
                "modules": false
            }
        ]
    ],
    "plugins": ["external-helpers"]
}
```

Examples of modules that I can't load are *math.js, nsolvejs, chroma.js, data.gui*, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is probably with commonjs plugin, it is used to transform cjs into es modules at build time, therefore you should include the cjs modules from node_modules instead of src.

```
 commonjs({
    include: 'node_modules/**'
 })
```

Comment: I was sure to have tried that at some point, but it must have been with a bad configuration anywhere else. But now it works, so thanks a lot :)