# `require` or `import` CommonJS node modules using rollup

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, commonjs, rollupjs

I am unsure whether I am supposed to use the `require` version or the `import` version.
It doesn't state that in the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rollup/plugin-commonjs) and I found a [statement in a Github issue](https://github.com/rollup/rollup/issues/1058#issuecomment-254187433) that

> Mixing import and require is definitely discouraged. The only way for Rollup to handle require statements is with rollup-plugin-commonjs, but that plugin will skip any files with import or export statements.

which could be interpreted as: "You need to still use `require` otherwise the common-js plugin will ignore your file and things will not work." or as "always use `import` everything else would constitute mixing". So that really confused me.

#### Context

I am trying to import a CommonJS library ([Citation-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/citation-js)) into a javascript module (really typescript but I hope this is not relevant here). Now the documentation of common-js tells me to do

```js
const Cite = require('common-js');
```

which tells me that it is a commonjs library (right?). Therefore I added

```js
import commonjs from "rollup-plugin-commonjs";
import { nodeResolve } from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
```

to my rollup config and put `plugins: [commonjs(), typescript(), nodeResolve()]` into the configuration.

Now vscode stops underlining everything and building the website with rollup works again. But the compiled javascript simply states `require('common-js')` and my browser complains that `require` is undefined.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

So I tried

```js
import Cite from 'common-js';
```

instead. But that resulted in the rollup build failing with

```sh
[!] Error: Unexpected token (Note that you need @rollup/plugin-json to import JSON files)
node_modules/@citation-js/core/package.json (2:8)
1: {
2:   "name": "@citation-js/core",
           ^
```

Now I could of course install that plugin. But I am not sure that is right, since the whole point of a tool like rollup should be that dependencies of dependencies should be resolved automatically right?

#### I have also tried

- [Can't import npm modules in commonjs with rollup : "require is not defined"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46131026/cant-import-npm-modules-in-commonjs-with-rollup-require-is-not-defined)
- This seemed like it would fix my problem: [Using Older Require Module With Rollup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61348898/using-older-require-module-with-rollup)

  But:

  - the `rollup-plugin-node-builtins` is apparently not maintained (npm protested with security vulnerabilities and I found this: https://github.com/rollup/rollup/issues/2881). EDIT: There is a new package [rollup-plugin-polyfill-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-polyfill-node) replacing that I guess.
  - `resolve` is no longer a member of `@rollup/plugin-node-resolve` so I assume that this has become `nodeResolve` which I am already using...
- EDIT: installing `@rollup/plugin-json` actually lets me build the site again (with a bunch of warnings)

  - `(!) Missing shims for Node.js built-ins` (which is not fixed by the `rollup-plugin-polyfill-node` above)
  - `(!) Missing global variable names`
  - `(!) Circular dependencies`
  - `(!) Unresolved dependencies`

  not sure what to do about these warnings

Comment: I now think that import is the correct way (for any future readers).

Comment: I also kept running into this problem. I had an old lib to maintain, and when I tried to rollup it to umd package, I came across this problem. I did not change "require" to "import", instead I used updated plugin @rollup/common-js, and set one of its option 'transformMixedEsModules' to true, which will enable mixed module transformations. May it helps for anyone who read this.